# Google Script - Consolidated operator syntax not working in IF statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, operators

## Conext

I would like my onEdit(e) function below to add or remove rows from a spreadsheet based on the new and old values of a cell. This requires the OR (||) operator in my IF statement to check the values. Below is my first attempt which sort of worked but led to some odd behavior such as rows appearing then disappearing (the second IF statement) after a single edit, two rows appearing whenever I hit the "delete" key, etc:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var newValue = e.value;
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;
  var targetRow = range.getRow();

//insert 2 rows if edited cell value = "a" or "b"
  if (newValue === "a" || "b") {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(targetRow, 2);
  } 

//delete 2 rows if former cell value was "a" or "b"
  if (oldValue === "a" || "b") {
    sheet.deleteRows(targetRow + 1, 2);
  }
}
```

#### Applications Currently Used

1. Google Sheets
2. Google Apps Script

#### What I've Tried So Far

When I changed my IF statements to restate the variable after each OR operator, the desired result was produced cleanly:

```
if (newValue === "a" || newValue === "b") {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(targetRow, 2);
  } 
  if (oldValue === "a" || oldValue === "b") {
    sheet.deleteRows(targetRow + 1, 2);
  }
```

#### Question

Is there a consolidated form of writing these statements that will continue to produce the desired result? As I continue writing this function, these IF statements are likely to become more complex and the same variable will need to be checked using OR and AND operators. It would be much easier to only state the variable name once for each operator.

To recap:

I would like to be able to write the consolidated format of the code as shown in the first code snippet:

```
if (newValue === "a" || "b") { //etc...
```

However, it only works properly when written in the longer version:

```
if (newValue === "a" || newValue == "b") { //etc...
```

Thank you!

Comment: In English grammar you can correctly use the following sentence.  `Is 1 equal to 2 or 3?`  That's what you are trying to do with JavaScript.  It makes perfect sense in English.  In JavaScript, it doesn't work.  There is no option to use a consolidated syntax.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the switch statement to consolidate.

```
switch (newValue) {
  case "a":
  case "b":
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(targetRow, 2);
    break;
  default:
}
```

You could add more cases there to "OR" the overall condition if required.

Comment: Great idea! I tried this and it worked, thank you. For the AND operator, would the switch cases be embedded within an IF statement?

Comment: You could use the `switch (true)` semantics, but it won't help consolidate any AND statement the way you originally wanted it. It helps for comparison operators though. eg: `switch(true) {
  case (y < x):
    //
    break;
  case (y > z):
    //
    break;
  case (y < 100):
    //
    break;
}`